# ASP.NET Session and target blank

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have seen a few posts regarding Session and using target blank to open a new page.
But I still don´t get it.

Im working with an application which opens from a link on an Intranet site. I guess it uses target blank to get it in a new window. (I don´t have the source).

If both windows are closed (My application and the Intranet site) it seems like the Session is destroyed. I need that to happen when my application is closed. (ie, still leaving the Intranet site open).

If I use the site in my testenvironment without opening it from a page with target blank, it seems like I get the expected behaviour.

Web.config has: pages enableSessionState="true"

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If both the application and the intranet website use the same session to the server, they will both keep it alive.

What you could do is destroy the session (Session.Abandon()) when the user closes the application.

Comment: Thanks.
I have earlier googled on how to capture browser close, but I havent found a good solution.

"If both the application and the intranet website use the same session to the server, they will both keep it alive"

Can I change this? Where?

(All users use IE7/8)

Answer (score 0):

If the applications are sharing sessions, then it will not be possible to end one of them while keeping the other one alive.

But you can capture the browser close to end a session ( which is not shared with your intranet site).

http://aspalliance.com/1294 gives a fair idea of how to do it.

I used the below javascript condition and it worked for 2 of 5 scenatrios:

```
  if (((window.event.clientX < 0) || (window.event.clientY < 0)) || (event.altKey == true && event.keyCode == 115)  {
```

alert('window is closing');
 PageMethods.AbandonSession();
}

But this is very IE specific and works only for single tab browser close using 'X' button on the browser window and for ALT+ F4.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi

Do you mean that it doesnt work with IE7/8 since it has multiple tabs?

Comment: I meant that the link should be the only one opened in the explorer window and there should not be more tabs in that window other than your link. ( Making it a single tab browser window). Then it will work. Otherwise I could not solve the issue myself with multi tab browser windows.